# How do you determine unique pairs of rational ratios of decimals?

Tags: decimal-expansion

This seems like a fairly simple question and I hope that it's just not my own stupidity guiding it. What i'm asking is that you could show any decimal as a ratio of rationals but in any situation how do you determine this.

Here is an example ratio 4/3=1.333333333..., now how could I determine the lowest number ratio of rationals for something like x/y=1.37. How could I determine "x" or "y" when they are unknown but they themselves cannot be decimals.

Comment: You might be interested in the use of the Stern-Bricot Tree to find rational approximations. http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-stern-brocot

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to find the [simple continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion of the number. Given a number in finite decimal expansion, you will be able to continue only so far and then at the end, you will probably have a relatively big partial quotient. You probably want to ignore that and convert the rest of the continued fraction into a quotient of integers.

Take the number $x=1.37$, for example. The simple continued fraction expansion of $x$ is $x=1+1/(2+1/(1+1/(2+1/(2+1/(1+1/3)))))=137/100.$ However, the last partial quotient of $3$ may not be good, and replacing $1/3$ with $0$ gives $37/27=1.370370\dots$ instead. Take the number $x=1.33$ as a simple example. The simple continued fraction expansion of $x$ is $x=1+1/(3+1/33)=133/100.$ However, we suspect $33$, and replacing $1/33$ with $0$ gives $1+1/3=4/3$ which is probably what we wanted.